# Is the sentence incomplete?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is the following sentence complete?

> "In this documentary we meet many girls from across the world, as they
>   come of age in the way their culture dictates, we see remarkable
>   heart-warming stories of bravery and humor."

Comment: It would be more useful if you share with us what makes you intuitively think the sentence is incomplete. -- FWIW, it's a run-on sentence to me, but technically the writer could claim asyndeton and say that it's fine as is.

Comment: Which conjunction can be used to join the following parts:

1. In this documentary we meet many girls from across the world

2. as they come of age in the way their culture dictates, we see remarkable heart-warming stories of bravery and humor.

Comment: The way I see it, you have three parts, each of which relates to "In this documentary". If you want to group it as two parts like you did in the comment, it'll be the best to split the two parts into two sentences. (Your 2nd part can be understood as *We see remarkable ... as they come of age ...*)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me the meaning of "come of age in the way their culture dictates"?

Comment: `come of age` means "become an adult" ([source](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+of+age)).

Answer (score 1):

As the sentence is phrased, it is a run-on with a comma splice.

> "In this documentary we meet many girls from across the world"

is a complete sentence.

> "As they come of age in the way their culture dictates, we see
>   remarkable, heart-warming stories of bravery and humor."

is a complete sentence as well.

Combining them with a comma creates the comma-splice.

How the piece should be rewritten is heavily context-dependent:

> "In this documentary, we meet many girls from across the world as they
>   come of age in the way their culture dictates. We see remarkable
>   heart-warming stories of bravery and humor."

Would  one legitimate rewrite
that eliminates the splice, but tends I think to weaken the second
sentence in that the "heart-warming stories" have an implicit origin
in the difficulties encountered by virtue of "coming of age."

Another alternative would be:

> "In this documentary, we meet many girls from across the world. As
>   they come of age in the way their culture dictates, we see remarkable
>   heart-warming stories of bravery and humor."